# Cannot see my Local IP adress in ipconfig

Tags: networking, ip, lan, ipconfig

1. I wanted to foward my port but I needed to know my LAN IP adress when I typed ipconfig /all this is what i did get

   2.LAN = Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı in my language btw

3.Where can I see my Lan IP to port foward

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

C:\Users\Selman>ipconfig /All

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : idea-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-6C-66-9D-71-24
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b4cf:366f:e0e0:4497%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 621412391
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-38-3A-13-02-05-DE-72-7A-47

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-05-DE-72-7A-47
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8d78:347d:2263:77f7%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 19 Ocak 2016 Salı 23:52:09
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 23 Ocak 2016 Cumartesi 00:03:54
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 253790596
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-38-3A-13-02-05-DE-72-7A-47

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-6C-66-9D-71-23
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Anchorfree HSS VPN Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-02-1D-D6-76
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Ağ Bağlantısı:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-6C-66-9D-71-27
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9F72CAF1-A870-4DAA-95A3-9BC2B890CD4E}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9E955E52-69A5-4E4F-844B-561236FE8766}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\Selman>
```

Comment: I believe its 192.168.1.102

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you mean the Wireless LAN Adapter labeled `Wireless LAN adapter Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı* 2`, it appears to not currently be associated with a wireless network, and thus, has no IP address.  Once it associates with the router's BSSID, it should acquire an IP address.  However, read further.

An inside-private IP address is needed in order to forward traffic from an outside-public network.  Since a router's DHCP server normally assigns IP addresses in a first-come, first-served manner, there's no guarantee that the IP address a particular interface gets today will be the same one it gets in the future,  unless...

In the router's DHCP configuration, make an IP reservation for a specific IP address and associate it with the MAC address of the adapter you wish to forward traffic towards.  Then, set up your IP forwarding rule to that IP address you've reserved.  This will ensure that the adapter will have the same IP address each time it boots up, and no other system will be given that IP number.  This will ensure that the forwarding rule you configure will remain valid in the future.

Comment: I made it like this but the result is same when I typr ipconfig all it still says media disconected
s 192.168.2.100 60:6c:66:9d:71:24 VLAN 1

Comment: Well, now you have to figure out why your WiFi adapter is not connecting to your router;  That's a different problem, which ought to be asked in a new question.  Unfortunately, I'm not well-versed on Windows networking issues any more.

Comment: Yes Im researching it but how can my laptop have internet connection if it doesnt connect to the router can it be a driver problem

Comment: I guess it's using a different interface.  Check your routing table, with `netstat -r` to see what interface the route 0.0.0.0 is using.

Comment: https://0bin.net/paste/ABEiaLrnrQSUyH9H#5RowNcCXS0Jwc5zQXWtyYsHkC98FNRLVP7HRQK+5O-w

Comment: According to the 0bin page, most of your traffic is going to 192.168.2.1, though an interface numbered 192.168.2.108.  That interface does not appear above.

However, you have another route, 0.0.0.0/1 (the lower half of IPv4;  0.0.0.0-127.255.255.255) pointing to 10.254.224.1, through an interface numbered 10.254.224.32; also not listed above.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.102(Preferred)

It has both IPv4 and IPv6 configured, however; it's preferring your IPv4 address.